# Pandas Dataframe - add columns to one dataframe from another

Tags: pandas

I am new to Python and trying to figure out to add columns to one dataframe from another. I have 2 Data frame:

Data Frame A: i = index

```
i | A | B | C

0 | 1 | 7 | 4

1 | 3 | 2 | 5

2 | 1 | 4 | 4

0 | 9 | 2 | 7

1 | 8 | 2 | 4

2 | 1 | 3 | 8
```

Data Frame B: i = index

```
i | X | Y | Z

0 | c | f | g

1 | k | j | i
```

I want my resultant dataframe to look like:

```
i | A | B | C | X | Y | Z

0 | 1 | 7 | 4 | c | f | g

1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | c | f | g

2 | 1 | 4 | 4 | c | f | g

0 | 9 | 2 | 7 | k | j | i

1 | 8 | 2 | 4 | k | j | i

2 | 1 | 3 | 8 | k | j | i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need create new index by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by index values and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) another `DataFrame`:

```
A.index = A.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
C = A.join(B).reset_index(drop=True)
print (C)
   A  B  C  X  Y  Z
0  1  7  4  c  f  g
1  3  2  5  c  f  g
2  1  4  4  c  f  g
3  9  2  7  k  j  i
4  8  2  4  k  j  i
5  1  3  8  k  j  i
```

Comment: why can't we do `pd.merge(A, B, left_index=True, right_index=True)` ?

Comment: @YOLO - yes, it is another solution, `pd.merge(A, B, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')` for left join